# CloudKit Enabled App Development to Production Deployment

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I have a CloudKit enabled app. I have deployed the schema from development to production. The app already has all the entitlements necessary to work. The first thing I noticed on production "Default Zone" for my record type is this:

[image]

Next, I installed the app on my device and tried to insert a record. But it did not work. No errors or anything just did not do anything!

Does anyone has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Goto to Record Types and select your Record Type then in the Metadata Indexes check the Record ID Query and save it.
Then click on Deployment tab and deploy your record types and move to the production mod to check whether the problem is solved or not:

[image: Follow The Steps In Image]